# LEDs blinking circuit problem

Tags: transistors, led

I tried the following circuit but the LEDs for me are always on and don't blink, i checked connectivity, changed capacitors and tested transistors but same problem. what could be the issue?
[image]

edit:
left transistor is 13001 s8d, right on is 13002 HJ B1

[image: picture of the setup:]

Comment: Show a photo of your setup and add in a part number and link to datasheet for your transistors.

Comment: Compare TO-92A, TO-92B and TO-92C transistor packages - it is easy to mix up base emitter and collector.

Comment: Wow, a legitimate breadboard! Haven't seen one of those in YEARS!

Comment: Those don't look like 47k resistors to me

Comment: yeah they'r 10k, is it that important?

Comment: Those green "resistors" could be "inductors" instead.

Comment: The resistance will change the frequency of the flashing, though 10k instead of 47k would probably be fine in this case. As Mike said though, green devices in these packages can be inductors, so you might have a pair of 10mH inductors instead. Measure their resistance (out of circuit) with a multimeter and confirm whether or not they are indeed 10k.

Comment: "*yeah they'r 10k, is it that important?*" That's why I asked for a photo. What else are you not telling us? Where's the link to the transistor datasheet?

Comment: It does look like the pinouts of the transistors are correct, though I don't know what the effect of using two mismatched transistors would be in this design

Comment: @Transistor I believe these are the datasheets: https://alltransistors.com/pdfdatasheet_cdil/cd13001.pdf and https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/888528/SEMTECH_ELEC/13002.html

Comment: +1 just because it's an awesome build up :)
Stupid question, always on means for your eyes or did you measure?

Comment: thanks :) for the measurements my multimeter is broken so i'm relying on my eyes atm till i get a new one.

Comment: Well you can't really determine whether the device is a resistor or an inductor just by looking at it.

Comment: turned out you are right those actually aren't resistors, i changed them for different ones and now the circuit works :) thanks for the help.

Comment: Good news! Thanks for the update!

Comment: Surprised some parts did not heat up or worse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh this is a simple one. Those sea-foam green "resistors" are actually inductors. The green color is used to indicate it is an axial lead inductor specifically so they wont be confused with resistors.

This question actually addresses this:

[How to visually tell the difference between axial inductors and common resistors?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/108108/how-to-visually-tell-the-difference-between-axial-inductors-and-common-resistors)