# What is this component value?

Tags: pcb, resistors, inductor

Note: It's broken so I can't measure it, and I don't know if it's a resistor or inductor.

[image]

Comment: May be helpful: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/108108/2028

Comment: What is the device it is mounted on? Are there any designators? By what means have you determined it is "broken"?

Comment: how do you know that you can't measure it?

Comment: If you look closely at the photo, there's a big crack in the component.

Comment: it has a crack 
and also suppose it's a resistor or inductor it should measure a resistance on the multimeter
It currently measure OL on the multimeter

Answer (score 1):

One way to tell if a resistor or inductor would be to crack it open and see what's inside, it's already broken so... not much to lose.

From my experience, this appears to be a 6.8\$\Omega\$ 2 W (maybe 1 W?) carbon composition resistor. Possibly part of a snubber circuit along with the capacitor behind it.

I'm not sure about the white and orange bands though, they may be a manufacturer specific code, possibly something safety related. It may have to be replaced with a specific type to maintain a safety rating.

It could be an inductor, in which case it would probably be 6.8 uH, but I'm leaning towards resistor, I've seen resistors of this style split open just like the one shown is.

It doesn't look like a complicated circuit, you could make a schematic of it and the location of the component in the circuit might give a better idea to what it is and what it's used for.

Comment: Since the orange is the widest band, why this is not a 3.9 ohm 10% fusible resistor?

Comment: @Justme Let me turn my head upside down a minute.... yeah, guess it could be that. :D

Comment: @GodJihyo Thanks for the reply, But if I crack it open.
How can I tell if it's a resistor or inductor ?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanAshraf If you know something about the circuit, it might be easier to guess which is it. It looks like it belongs to a mains supply input filter section on a PCB, an there seem to be a common mode choke and filter cap, so all guesses point that this is a resistor for inrush current limiting. If it is a resistor, it may be a special resistor for safety, and must not be replaced with just any resistor or it might be dangerous and cause a fire.